# Exception in parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

When i am loading following JSON usin $.getJSON method of jquery i get following error
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**
The JSON is created programmatically in a servlet using Java's Simple JSON library so i think there is a little chance of structure error in json
Following is the JSON which is loaded

```
{"links":[{"link":"http:\/\/projects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com\/YTDownload?url=http:\/\/o-o---preferred---iad09s20---v17---lscache7.c.youtube.com\/videoplayback?upn=OE7v3mttmjE!sparams=cp%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire!fexp=922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C911406%2C912706!key=yt1!itag=37!ipbits=8!signature=3E14ACACF3CD2F3DB18C6D0D54C00A49E6CAA2BE.B6CD8982AAD85086CC1CCA42F9207FF9AF6DBC84!mv=m!sver=3!mt=1345701731!ratebypass=yes!source=youtube!ms=au!gcr=us!expire=1345726167!ip=50.19.68.176!cp=U0hTSldNVF9LUUNOM19PR1hCOjAzTWtjV2V2eTRu!id=9d8c9310d90eae67!quality=hd1080!fallback_host=tc.v17.cache7.c.youtube.com!type=video\/mp4&title=Tujhe Bhula Diya \/ Hello - Gaurav (Synchronicity)\n      - YouTube.mp4","type":"mp4"},{"link":"http:\/\/projects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com\/YTDownload?url=http:\/\/o-o---preferred---iad09s20---v16---lscache6.c.youtube.com\/videoplayback?ip=50.19.68.176!upn=OE7v3mttmjE!sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cgcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire!fexp=922401%2C920704%2C912806%2C911406%2C912706!mt=1345701731!key=yt1!algorithm=throttle-factor!burst=40!ipbits=8!itag=17!sver=3!signature=1C4B63A105890A1B7C63563C1CCDB2187F7FCF74.64100D94E68D0327F78C1BCD89ECB77E1D2D83A3!mv=m!source=youtube!ms=au!gcr=us!expire=1345726167!factor=1.25!cp=U0hTSldNVF9LUUNOM19PR1hCOjAzTWtjV2V2eTRu!id=9d8c9310d90eae67!quality=small!fallback_host=tc.v16.cache6.c.youtube.com!type=video\/3gpp&title=Tujhe Bhula Diya \/ Hello - Gaurav (Synchronicity)\n      - YouTube.3gpp","type":"3gpp"}]}
```

Here's the code that does the `$.getJSON()`:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://projects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com/YTGrabber?url=http://you‌​tube.com/watch?v=nYyTENkOrmc&feature=g-all-lik&callback=?',
         function(data) { alert('loaded'); });
});
```

Comment: `$('button').click(function()
    {
     $.getJSON('http://projects-sushilkumar.rhcloud.com/YTGrabber?url=http://youtube.com/watch?v=nYyTENkOrmc&feature=g-all-lik&callback=?',function(data)
     {
      alert('loaded');
     });
    });`
this is the code which loads JSON

Comment: You seem to be doing a jsonp request - does that server respond appropriately or does it just return plain JSON?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes that server responds appropriately. Infact it sets the content type to text/json

Comment: @nnnnnn when i saved the same JSON in a file and decoded it it worked like a charm. Any ideas about why is this happening?

Comment: If it's a jsonp request the content type should be `application/javascript`, because the JSON should be wrapped in a JS function call.

Answer (score 0):

It is the newline characters (`\n`) in the JSON that are causing it to fail. Try removing them first.

Alternatively, try escaping the `\` (backslash) in `\n` by using an additional `\`, i.e. `\\n`. You can do that on either the server (probably best) or the client.

Comment: `"\n"` is valid in JSON. If you were constructing a JSON _in JavaScript_ from a string literal _then_ you'd have to say `"\\n"`, but the string created by that string literal would have two characters, a `"\"` and an `"n"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn i have removed all the `\n` from the JSON but still getting the error